# php: simplexml_load_file outputs different on different environment

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using `simplexml_load_file` to load xml and import items in db. However, in my case there is inconsistency with how simple_load_file function works on different environment. For eg, if I run the following code:

```
$xmlPath = __DIR__.'/../files/xml/data.xml';
$xmlElements = simplexml_load_file($xmlPath);

foreach ($xmlElements->bien as $element) {
    var_dump($element);
}
```

The problem is that the properties for `$element` comes our different on my local and on my development server. Please check the screenshot at [output of $element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjBZn.png).

The output for my local is as follows:

```
public 'type_diffusion' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
      public 'code' => string 'FERME' (length=5)
      public 'designation' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'Fermé au réseau ' (length=18)
          1 => string 'Closed to the network ' (length=22)
          2 => string 'Im Netzwerk nicht verfügbar ' (length=29)
```

And on development server it is as follows:

```
["type_diffusion"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (2) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(5) "FERME"
    ["designation"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#41 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["lang"]=>
          string(2) "fr"
        }
        [0]=>
        string(18) "Fermé au réseau "
      }
      [1]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#42 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["lang"]=>
          string(2) "en"
        }
        [0]=>
        string(22) "Closed to the network "
      }
      [2]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#43 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["lang"]=>
          string(2) "de"
        }
        [0]=>
        string(29) "Im Netzwerk nicht verfügbar "
      }
    }
  }
```

The part of xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Agence>
  <date>27.04.2020 16:23:42</date>
  <bien>
    <introducteur>oui</introducteur>
    <type_diffusion>
      <code>FERME</code>
      <designation lang="fr">Fermé au réseau </designation>
      <designation lang="en">Closed to the network </designation>
      <designation lang="de">Im Netzwerk nicht verfügbar </designation>
    </type_diffusion>
  </bien>
</Agence>
```

On my local, the property `type_diffusion -> designation` is array and all of its items are string in my local system. But on my development server, the items inside the array `type_diffusion -> designation`  is of type `SimpleXMLElement`.

I checked the documentation for `simplexml_load_file` but could not find any thing useful. Do you guys have the same issue ? How do you solve his inconsistencies between environment ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Looks like you have something over-riding the definition of `var_dump`. It doesn't matter, though, both are trying to tell you the same thing, and not doing terribly well (there aren't really any arrays there, only objects with lots of "magic"). Just look at [the examples in the manual](https://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) and reference the elements and attributes you need.

Comment: @IMSoP not really. There is no overriding the definition of var_dump. I have different output with & without var_dump. I checked with print_r for instance.

Comment: @IMSoP The problem is that I am saving the content of type_diffusion by json_encode in db, and it gives me problem when I json_decode later in my app. On my local, I have strings inside the array and on development server I have SimpleXmlElement as items... And this is giving me a lot of issues.

Comment: Actually, I do have an idea: I'd put money on **this** being what's over-riding `var_dump`: https://xdebug.org/docs/display That shouldn't have any effect on `json_encode`, though, so feel free to [edit] to include an example of the actual problem you have with that. (My main advice will remain "don't do that", but I might be able to explain why you're seeing what you're seeing.)

Comment: @IMSoP yes, but in my case (in local) I have array and not SimpleXmlElement. And for it is pretty ok at-least with my environment. My curiosity about the different output on local and development environment. I also ran the same code in mac & windows local system. They both return array. It is only on dev that is causing issue. Btw, did you tried the code in your local ? What do you have ? Thx for quick replies :)

Comment: I very much doubt they are actually returning array. `var_dump` and `print_r` just aren't very good at displaying SimpleXML objects. Again, feel free to come up with an example showing your _actual_ issue (with `json_encode`), otherwise I will suggest that this Question is closed as not reproducible, because the difference you show is just XDebug's formatting. **Here's a clearer piece of code to show that they are in fact objects: https://3v4l.org/W4pFF**

Comment: It happened that simplexml_load_file ooutput different for different version of php as seen in https://3v4l.org/thmN6#v720 For php versions 7.2.0 - 7.3.16, 7.4.0 - 7.4.4, the output for my code is string inside array for type_diffusion -> designation and for php versions 7.3.17, 7.4.5, the items are SimpleXmlElement. Now my question is there any way I can have same output in different php versions ? Thx

Comment: Again, **the difference is only in the debug output**. Look at my previous link, the `->bien->type_diffusion->designation` elements **are always SimpleXML objects**. I'm voting to close this question. If you have a reproducible problem involving `json_encode`, [edit] it in and tag me in a comment, or open a new question.